# BindProperty is not binding to incoming JSON in request body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

This the request's body:

```
{
    userId: 382,
    serviceName: 'Translation'
}
```

And this is a property on my API controller:

```
[BindProperty]
public string ServiceName { get; set; }
```

But it's null. How should I configure ASP.NET Core to bind from JSON too?

I'm using .NET 6.

Comment: You can just Replace [BindProperty] with [FromBody] , if it doesn't work, you need to provide your controller and model.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps make FromBody explicit and specify the name, in case it is related to the casing not matching.

```
 [FromBody(Name = "serviceName")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Creating a class for the method
public class data{
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public string Service { get; set; }
}

// If you wish to do in method
public void getdata([FromBody] data recivedata) {

    data d = new data();
    d.UserId = recivedata.UserId;
    d.Service = recivedata.Service;

    // perform any action with the data
}
```